# CMD ECHO doesn't print to file after redirecting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I'm trying to run a bat file from within another bat file and redirect the output. That's working fine. However, after that call to the bat file has finished, I want to print to one of the files I've been redirecting to, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here's what I'm doing right now.

```
@ECHO OFF
call %1 2> error.log 1> compile.log
echo Complete >> error.log
```

My hope is that the Complete text is appended to the log when bat file finished running. However, it never writes out. The log only contains output from the bat file I'm calling.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 different reasons for this behavior:

1. The batch file called with `call %1` changes the current working directory. This results in `Complete` written to a different `error.log` as before because working directory has changed in the meantime. The new current working directory could be also write-protected resulting in no `error.log` created at all.
2. The batch file called with `call %1` contains command `exit` without parameter `/B` which results in an immediate exit of running command line process. In this case the line with `echo` below `call` is never executed. See short help output in a command prompt window after entering either `help exit` or `exit /?` about `exit /B`.

Comment: This solved it for me. I thought I had checked, but it turns out the other bat file was changing directories.